# Does Android keep activity logs or save keystrokes?

Tags: samsung, stock-android, privacy

I want to know whether Android phones records activity logs of what I have done in a whole day. I've already checked that there is no Carrier IQ.

Is this true that after switching off the phone all activity logs vanish? Does my Android phone keep saving what keystrokes I typed? (I'm using Samsung keyboard.) Do all activity logs and keystrokes gets upload to my Google account server or any other account like Samsung?

Answer (score 1):

No, stock Android doesn't record everything you do in a day. There are a few things to bear in mind, though.

First, because Android is open-source, the manufacturer, and your carrier if you bought the phone from a carrier, can change the OS however they like. They might have changed it to add a log like you describe, so though Android itself doesn't record all your activity, I can't say for certainty whether **your phone** does or not.

Second, there's nothing to stop individual apps keeping records. For example, Chrome keeps a record of what websites you visit, and if you have "Web history" turned on, it syncs that information with your Google account. Other apps might use *analytics* to track what you do inside that app, and send that information to the app's author. Apps have access to a lot of information, even some information not directly related to the app (such as what other apps you have installed), so you have to trust the app not to do this.

Keyboard apps are another example of this. They learn what words you have typed, and maybe *collocations* of words (for example, if you type "Cambridge" followed by "Circus", it might save this in order to better predict it in future). Whether this information is uploaded to any server depends on the particular keyboard app.

The log you might have heard about in Android isn't an "activity log" at all: it contains debugging information for developers to see what apps are going, and to help find and fix problems. It's not intended to log what you're doing, though sometimes the information in there could be used to identify particular actions, and what apps you're using. Exactly what information this log contains depends on the phone you have, and it differs from app to app.

As you've mentioned, the log is only in memory and so it's lost when the device reboots. It's also a fixed size (the exact size is different on different devices), so over the course of a day newer log entries will continually overwrite older entries.

Answer (score 0):

The  above does give your answer I am only going to explain it in brief

Following are some of the ways through which key logging is done.

**Google**:-Whenever you open the Google search and type your search it will be stored for the future to do things like auto-complete, display advertisements in your phone etc.

**T9 dictionary**:-Whenever you enter a custom word more then once it will be stored in the dictionary by default. The input could be anything passwords ,bank account no's ,name anything.
It's for the ease of the user these custom words are stored. Next time when you just enter the first letter of the custom word then the remaining word get's displayed for selection. Thereby relieving the user the need to type the whole word manually.

While installing apps from the play store or any other source from outside always make sure that the permissions required suits to the kind of application it's made for.

**For ex**:-There are some apps like flash light which would require permission only for the camera to display the flash but as you would un mindfully go ahead and install then your phone's data could be distributed to third party's because if you have carefully viewed the permissions required then it would also ask for some unwanted permission (view contacts/call log etc.) which is not at all related in its functionality or usage.

In this way whenever you call or whatever number you have dialled would be accessible to the flash light app and will be secretly transferred to its server whenever there's a connection to the internet.